# Python: Replace the first nth matching letter to another letter

Tags: python, csv, replace

This is related to trimming a csv file process.
I have a mar-formatted csv file that has 4 columns, but the last column has too many (and unknown number of) commas.

I want to replace the delimiter to another character such as "|"
For example, string = "a,b,c,d,e,f" into "a|b|c|d,e,f"

The following codes works, but I like to find a better and efficient way to process large size txt file.

```
sample_txt='a,b,c,d,e,f'
temp=sample_txt.split(",")
output_txt='|'.join(temp[0:3])+'|'+','.join(temp[3:])
```

Comment: Is your text large because of many lines or because very long lines? If you have lots of short lines I doubt you can do much better than what you already have...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python has the perfect way to do this, with `str.replace`:

```
>>> sample_txt='a,b,c,d,e,f'
>>> print(sample_txt.replace(',', '|', 3))
a|b|c|d,e,f
```

`str.replace` takes an optional third argument (or fourth if you count `self`) which dictates the maximum number of replacements to happen.

Comment: Thanks for the nice and neat solution. I should check the details of the python basic functions one more time.

Answer (score 1):

```
sample_txt='a,b,c,d,e,f'
output_txt = sample_txt.replace(',', '|', 3)
```